# Is it possible to add a CCLabel to a CCSprite in a CCSpriteBatchNode?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a CCSpriteBatchNode that is added to my Scene.

I have a CCSprite that is created with "initWithSpriteFrameName," then I add it to my batch node.

The sprite displays correctly.  However, after that I add a CCLabelTTF as a child to the CCSprite, and the app crashes with the following error:

"CCSprite is not using the same texture id"

Is there any way to add the Label as a child node of the sprite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the label only if you don't add the CCSprite to a CCSpriteBatchNode. CCSpriteBatchNode only allows CCSprite as children, and that also extends to children of children.

If that's not an option, simply add the label to the scene hierarchy elsewhere and then update the position of the label to the sprite's position using an update method, in order to synchronize the label's and sprite's positions.

Comment: I did a bunch of research and concluded adding the sprite as described in my question can't be done.  However, I did the same thing as your second suggestion, then later refactored my code to do the same thing as your first one.  After all that I saw your post.  =)

Comment: Well, at least you got confirmation. :)

Comment: CCLabelTTF inherits from CCSprite, so it should be possible to add it to a CCSpriteBatchNode. The problem is that CCSpriteBatchNode is created using an image (usually a PNG atlas), but I don't know if it is possible to specify a font image and use it with CCLabelTTF.